# How to get response in desired format from postgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have three tables. Course, Topics, Subtopics. They all contain a respective name, id, description, etc.
My query is to get all the data from the database.

```
select course.course_id, course_name, course_description,
   topic.topic_id, topic_name, topic_description,
   subtopic.subtopic_id, subtopic_name 
from 
course join topic on course.course_id = topic.course_id    
join subtopic on topic.topic_id = subtopic.topic_id
order by course.course_id, topic.topic_id, subtopic.subtopic_id;
```

The format I'm getting is array of objects. The desired output is

```
course:[
     {
       course_id:1,
       topics:[
          {
            topic_id:1,
            subtopics:[
                        subtopic_id:1
                      ]
          }
       ]
     },
     ...
     ...
     ...
]
```

Is there a way to query my DB in such a way that my output is in this format? Javascript's approach to format data optimally in such fomat is also welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JSON aggregation:

```
select c.course_id, c.course_name, c.course_description,
    jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
            'topic_id',          t.topic_id,
            'topic_name',        t.topic_name,
            'topic_description', t.topic_description,
            'subtopics',         st.subtopics
        )
        order by t.topic_id
    ) topics 
from course c
inner join topic t on c.course_id = t.course_id    
cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
            'subtopic_id',   st.subtopic_id, 
            'subtopic_name', st.subtopic_name
        )
        order by st.subtopic_id
    ) subtopics
    from subtopic st 
    where st.topic_id = t.topic_id
) st
group by c.course_id
order by c.course_id
```

You can add another level of aggregation if want a scalar result made of a big JSONB object, as shown in your resultset:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
    'courses',
    jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
            'course_id',          course_id,
            'course_name',        course_name
            'course_description', course_description
            'topics',             topics
        )
    )
    order by order by course_id
) result
from (
    select c.course_id, c.course_name, c.course_description,
        jsonb_agg(
            jsonb_build_object(
                'topic_id',          t.topic_id,
                'topic_name',        t.topic_name,
                'topic_description', t.topic_description,
                'subtopics',         st.subtopics
            )
            order by t.topic_id
        ) topics 
    from course c
    inner join topic t on c.course_id = t.course_id    
    cross join lateral (
        select jsonb_agg(
            jsonb_build_object(
                'subtopic_id',   st.subtopic_id, 
                'subtopic_name', st.subtopic_name
            )
            order by st.subtopic_id
        ) subtopics
        from subtopic st 
        where st.topic_id = t.topic_id
    ) st
    group by c.course_id
) t
```

Comment: @eras'q: is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: I went through your query again and it was difficult to understand. Can you please add some explanation? Also, Can we optimize the above query?